# Java InetAddressClass getAllByNAme method

Tags: java, inetaddress

I am new to Java programming ,and there is a topic of networking,and my networking concept are weak,so could any one help me out with these methods
What does getAllByName()  method returns,it is written that it returns IP addresses of the host?what does this host mean?and does the host doesn't only have one IP address?

If someone could explain the basic concept of networking,so that I get to know what basically is IP address what does host mean,what does that method return

how come google.com is a host?

Comment: Best resource: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address

Comment: but what about the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every machine connected to a communications network is identified by a **unique number**.

In the case of the telephone network, each phone has a unique phone number associated with it, otherwise it cannot be used. Similarly, in an IP network, like the Internet, every machine (also called a host) must have at least one unique number, called the **IP address** (it may actually have more, e.g. routers have multiple IP addresses). Otherwise, that machine (host) cannot be used in (connected to) the IP network.

IP addresses (like telephone numbers) are difficult for people to remember, so we use host names (usually similar to domain names) to refer to machines, e.g. `google.com` or `www.microsoft.com` instead of an IP address (similarly, we save telephone numbers in the memory of our cell phone under the corresponding people's names). Each host name is translated automatically into an IP address (e.g., using [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)), because computers do not "understand" names, they "understand" numbers (IP addresses).

So, the machine (host) where the website of `Google` is stored, will have an IP address, to which the domain `google.com` will be translated every time a user puts that domain name in the browser. (Actually, there are many such machines, but let's assume the simplest case.)

With respect to the `InetAddress` class, the `getAllByname()` method just returns all the IP addresses associated with the host name supplied to the method as a string parameter, as per the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName%28java.lang.String%29). `Java` encapsulates each IP address in an `InetAddress` object, so the return value of the method is an array of `InetAddress` objects, with as many members as IP addresses in the machine (host) specified in the string supplied to the method. Typically, the first of these IP addresses is the one the `getByName()` method returns.

Comment: thank you for such a wonderful answer..one thing more could you explain what is the difference between getByName() and getallByNAme() then?

Comment: The getByName() method just returns one address, which is typically the first of the addresses returned by the getAllByName(). Go to the documentation page of Oracle, it explains all there. If my answer was helpful, you are welcome to upvote and select it as the answer to your question. :-)